# How to echo counts of for loop just once without multiple echoing?

Tags: php, codeigniter, flush

I guess the question is clear. What i want is to print count and update the same echo for the next loop or after certain sleep. But when i run the below code multiple echo is done. I just want to echo once and update/replace the last echo. I don't want to use html/javascript , i want this to be achieved in PHP. Below is the code.

```
<?php
if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();

for ($i = 0; $i<50000; $i++){

         echo $i;   

        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(1);

}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: This is not how it works. Everything in PHP is runned server side, and when it's finished, the complete code is sent to apache, who sent it to your browser. I guess what you want is : display 1, then errase 1 and display 2, then erase 2 and display 3... etc. This is really easy in JS, but php is really not made for it.

Comment: In fact just to be complete, yes you can start to display in client browser before php has finished, but still, you can't erase what has been sent to the browser, without using JS.

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly AF... but it works...

```
<style>
div.container { position:relative ; width:50px;height:50px; }
div.count { 
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:#FFF;
    width:50px ;
    height:50px ;
}
</style>
<div style="position:relative;"><?php

    if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();

    for ( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ )
    {
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        echo '<div class="count">'.$i.'</div>' ;
        sleep(1) ;
    }

    ob_end_flush();

?></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

> You can also use break; statement in your loop,to stop echoing.

```
 for ( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ )
{
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    echo '<div class="count">'.$i.'</div>' ;
    break;       
}
```